# Why is it beneficial to change state w/ actions in redux?

Tags: redux

From: https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles

> State is read-only. The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object describing what happened. This ensures that neither the views nor the network callbacks will ever write directly to the state. Instead, they express an intent to transform the state. Because all changes are centralized and happen one by one in a strict order, there are no subtle race conditions to watch out for. As actions are just plain objects, they can be logged, serialized, stored, and later replayed for debugging or testing purposes.

Two questions arise for me from this...

1. How is redux enforcing that changes happen in a strict order? If I change state synchronously then I don't see why this would ever be a problem. If I want to change state after async event 1 and async event 2 in order then wouldn't I have to do something like use callbacks or promises regardless of whether I'm using redux to ensure that the state changes in the order I expect?
2. Why is it easier to log an action? If I weren't using redux, couldn't I just console.log every state change I make to make it easier for debugging and testing? Am I just saving the time of writing console.log upon each state change by learning redux?

Comment: 1. You don't have asynchronous state changes, that's the point. You may have state changes that are triggered by things that were asynchronous, that's different. 2. *"... serialized, stored and later replayed"* - are you going to write all of that for each state change too?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I get point two now. So basically it would be really hard to store my state in a database upon each change if my state was scattered throughout my app. The redux store is essentially a JS object w/ your state and functions to observe the state?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. redux's execution is synchronous so when you dispatch an action, you're executing a a method on the redux store, which call the reducer to compute the new state. The concept of "async actions" don't exist in redux, which is why you have a host of solutions to enable them: redux-thunk, redux-saga, redux-observable and so on. All "async actions" library eventually have to execute the dispatch function synchronously to change the redux state.
2. In a well-written redux applications, changes to any state contained within the redux store could only have been caused by an action dispatched from somewhere within the application that has access to the dispatch function. This allows you to have total control and knowledge of where and how state changes happen. That's the main selling point of redux: "predictable state container." You can certainly store your local state in some global variable and manually mutate it but then you'll have to use something like [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) (which is actually deprecated with no replacement in sight) on that state variable to monitor changes to it.

Comment: Regarding point 1 I guess I'm still unclear what the benefit is to redux being synchronous? Since state changes are presumably always synchronous unless you use an async function to do it like React's setState. And I haven't used redux middleware yet, but are you saying they somehow get around the scenario where state changes may not be predictable if async event 1 takes longer than normal so async event 2 happens first? And anyway, why couldn't I enforce the order of events using callbacks or promises?

Comment: [1/4] Your question 1 asked why state changes are guaranteed to happen in strict order and my answer is "that's just how redux works." To address the new concern you raised, yes state changes will indeed be more unpredictable when you have "async actions" because now time is also a factor in addition to the action being dispatched. For example, AJAX requests 1 and 2 (for an autocomplete box) sent out in that order may come back in reverse order and potentially mess up your state.

Comment: [2/4] To answer your questions why callbacks and promises might not help you enforce the order, let's look at how redux-thunk middleware help with async actions. For each "trigger" (say, a data fetch), the middleware dispatches an event that tells the redux state to switch into a "pending" state (e.g. so you can show loadding spinners) while the middleware performs the async activity (e.g. actually send out the fetch request).

Comment: [3/4] When the async activity is finished, the middleware dispatches an action telling the redux state about the activity's success or failure (so that the UI can be updated accordingly). Given the way such a middleware works, each async "trigger" corresponds to individual actions and are totally unaware of each other. It's possible to coordinate multiple async actions with more advanced middlewares like redux-observable.

Comment: [4/4] If you're interested, I wrote a tutorial on how temporal dynamics (just like the race condition that you mentioned) can be tested rigorously using redux-observable in a post on my blog: https://www.huy.dev/marble-diagrams-redux-observable-2018-05/. The "Quick recap" section hopefully gives you a sense of why these middlewares exist.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'm still confused regarding why callbacks and promises might not help you enforce the order. In case this helps, My assumption is you could always do something like async event 1 returns a promise and in it's then you could dispatch action 1 synchronously and then start async event 2, which upon its completion dispatches action 2 synchronously. Presumably then the redux state would switch off of the pending state once async event 1 is complete and then quickly go into a pending state again once async event 2 starts.

Comment: If in response to a single trigger, async activity 1 needs to occur followed by async activity 2 then you can ensure that they execute in that order by just putting them in a single thunk (with appropriate use of either `.then` chaining if using raw `Promise`s or consecutive `await` statements if inside an `async` function). My point was that if trigger 1 leads to async activity 2 and trigger 2 leads to async activity 2 then even if trigger 1 happens before trigger 2, it's hard to coordinate the order of completion of the two async activities unless you reach for sth like `redux-observable`.